# Savon soap request ruby format

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I currently working on new project and I am pretty much new to savon. 
I am currently using ruby-1.8.7 and savon-1.0.0 and I have below SOAP XML request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<web:InvokeComponent1 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<PartnerName xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</PartnerName>
<ComponentName xsi:type="xsd:string">TestingServices</ComponentName>
<arg1Value xsi:type="xsd:string">[CONTROL]
RequestID=83f6baab
RequestTime=13:14:15
RequestDate=08/08/2013
GenerateLead=N
Auto=Y
</arg1Value>
<RaUID xsi:type="xsd:string">username</RaUID>
<RaPW xsi:type="xsd:string">password1</RaPW>
<AgNO xsi:type="xsd:string">12345</AgNO>
</web:InvokeComponent1>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my Savon code I have written to this request automation, obviously below mentioned code is not working as I need some inputs.

1. I am not sure where to include soapenv:Header, I tried putting inside request as shown in below code (currently commented) but I am getting 'undefined method `header=' for # (NoMethodError)'. where to include header in savon request?
2. in SOAP request name, I have an additional attribute soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" where should I include this additional attribute.

   ```
   client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl|
   wsdl.document = "https://www.abc.com/webservices/RemotePublicGateway.cfc?wsdl"  # this is not actual WSDL
   end

   testing_string = '[CONTROL]
   RequestID=83f6baab
   RequestTime=13:14:15
   RequestDate=08/08/2013
   GenerateLead=N
   Auto=Y'

    response = client.request :web, "InvokeComponent1" do
   #client.header = { }
    soap.body = {
   :PartnerName  => 'ABC', :attributes! => { :PartnerName => { 'xsi:type' => "xsd:string" } },
   :ComponentName => 'TestingServices', :attributes! => { :ComponentName => { 'xsi:type' => "xsd:string" } },
   :arg1Value => testing_string, :attributes! => { :arg1Value => { 'xsi:type' => "xsd:string" } },
   :RaUID => 'username', :attributes! => { :RaUID => { 'xsi:type' => "xsd:string" } },
   :RaPW => 'password1', :attributes! => { :RaPW => { 'xsi:type' => "xsd:string" } },
   :AgNO=> '12345', :attributes! => { :AgNO => { 'xsi:type' => "xsd:string" } }
   }
   end
   ```

Comment: savon 1.0.0 is deprecated.  Why are you using it?  Why are you using ruby 1.8.7 on a new project?

Comment: Ok, let me try with newer version of Savon, this project is part of already existing bigger project which is using 1.8.7 I can't just switch to newer version for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Added below line after 'soap.body' values and it worked with SAVON 1.0.0 too and with Ruby 1.8.7

```
:AgNO=> 'XXXXXXXXX...}},
:order!     => [:PartnerName, :ComponentName,:arg1Value,:RaUID,:RaPW,:AgNO]
}
```